# Existing ruby method that converts abbreviated US state names to full state names

Tags: ruby

Does anybody know if any common Ruby libraries have this capability?

For example

```
'AZ'.to_full_state
=> 'Arizona'
```

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [madison](https://rubygems.org/gems/madison/versions/0.5.0) gem, available at Rubygems.

Comment: Looks good. Turns out my organization has an internal library that we use, but this is useful. I was expecting this to be part of `active_support`...